# Why have certain Facebook API methods e.g. 'ME' stopped working?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

A Codeigniter site I set up about 12 months using FB PHP SDK to implement FB auth, album access and various other FB functions has now stopped working. I found a fix for one bug, but I have more and could do with knowing what's caused it. I'm guessing my version of the FB PHP SDK might be out of date, but I can't see any version number in the code.

ERROR:

```
$data = $this->facebook->api('/me');
```

> Error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: An active access
>   token must be used to query information about the current user.
>   thrown in
>   C:\inetpub\mysite.com\public_html\application\libraries\base_facebook.php
>   on line 1108

FIX:

```
$data = $this->facebook->api($userId);
```

ERROR:

```
$sql = SELECT aid, owner, name, object_id FROM album WHERE owner = "USERID";
$this->facebook->api( array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $sql ) );
```

> Error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: 102: Session key invalid
>   or no longer valid   thrown in
>   C:\inetpub\mysite.com\public_html\application\libraries\base_facebook.php
>   on line 1108

Line 1107-1127 from base_facebook.php

```
  protected function throwAPIException($result) {
    $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
    switch ($e->getType()) {
      // OAuth 2.0 Draft 00 style
      case 'OAuthException':
        // OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 style
      case 'invalid_token':
        // REST server errors are just Exceptions
      case 'Exception':
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        if ((strpos($message, 'Error validating access token') !== false) ||
            (strpos($message, 'Invalid OAuth access token') !== false) ||
            (strpos($message, 'An active access token must be used') !== false)
        ) {
          $this->destroySession();
        }
        break;
    }

    throw $e;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe your app took use of the `offline` permission, which has been removed in later days, or are not refreshing the `extended_token`?

Comment: _“I'm guessing my version of the FB PHP SDK might be out of date”_ – well then try updating that first. And the error message is quite specific about what the reason is – so check your access token.

Comment: Yes I can try the new SDK but wanted to see if anyone knew the reason before, in case updating caused other issues. I can't see why there would be an access token issue as api('/me') doesn't work and api($userId) does work when tested at the same time.

Comment: I have installed and tested with latest FB PHP SDK and I get same errors.

Comment: have you resolved this? i am having the exact same problem